# Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers error on Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Please I am new to Azure Devops. I am trying to setup Azure build pipeline for my Dockerized application. I used the classic editor to create the pipeline. The image builds but when it gets to push, I get the following error message;

> "Get ***/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
>   (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"

Note that I have a Private Registry which works if I push image from Powershell. I can also use the api endpoints of the Private Registry like going to ...v2/_catalog.

Please, does anyone have an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through this with my team, we found out that our firewall was blocking requests from Azure DevOps. It is working now.
Thanks.